# compiling a jrxml with sciptlet using ant

Tags: java, ant, jasper-reports, ireport, scriptlet

I'm trying to compile a jrxml using ant.
I've created my jrxml on iReports so I dont have a build.xml.
When runing ant command, it asks for a build.xml.
I created this file in the same repertory as my jrxml but I dont know what I should put into it to link my jrxml to my scriptlet jar.
I'll apreaciate your help, I'm a kind of lost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the report template with help of the ***net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask*** ant task.

The sample taken from [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/antcompile/index.html#antcompile):

```xml
<path id="runClasspath">
    <pathelement location="${path_to_jasper_libs}"/>
    <pathelement path="${path_to_scriplet}\scriplet.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
  <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="compile1"> 
  <mkdir dir="./build/reports"/> 
  <jrc 
    srcdir="./reports"
    destdir="./build/reports"
    tempdir="./build/reports"
    keepjava="true"
    xmlvalidation="true">
   <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
   <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
  </jrc>
</target>

<target name="compile2">
  <mkdir dir="./build/reports"/> 
  <jrc 
    destdir="./build/reports"
    tempdir="./build/reports"
    keepjava="true"
    xmlvalidation="true">
   <src>
    <fileset dir="./reports">
     <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
    </fileset>
   </src>
   <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
  </jrc> 
</target>
```

The quote from the site:

> In addition to the srcdir and the destdir attributes, the jrc custom
>   Ant task shipped with JasperReports supports the following attributes:
>
> compiler : Name of the class that implements the JRCompiler
>   interface to be used for compiling the reports (optional).
>
> xmlvalidation : Flag to indicate whether the XML validation should be
>   performed on the source report template files (true by default).
>
> tempdir : Location to store the temporarily generated files (the
>   current working directory by default).
>
> keepjava : Flag to
>   indicate if the temporary Java files generated on the fly should be
>   kept and not deleted automatically (false by default).

The working sample:

The ***SampleJRScriptlet*** class:

```java
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;

public class SampleJRScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

    public String doubleField(String value) {
        return Strings.repeat(value, 2);
    }
}
```

The report template to compile (the **report_with_scriplet.jrxml** file):

```xml
<jasperReport ... scriptletClass="SampleJRScriptlet">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/Northwind/Customers]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CustomerID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CustomerID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CompanyName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ContactName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContactName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ContactTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContactTitle]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.doubleField("$F{CustomerID}")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CompanyName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ContactName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ContactTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

My ant script (the **compile_report.xml** file):

```xml
<project default="compile" basedir=".">
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="./../../target/alternateLocation">
            <include name="jasperreports-4.1.2.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-logging-1.0.2.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-digester-1.7.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-collections-2.1.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar"/>
            <include name="groovy-all-1.0-jsr-05.jar"/>
        </fileset> 
    </path>

    <path id="runClasspath">
        <path refid="classpath"/> 
        <pathelement path="./../../target/myscriplet.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="./compiled_jasper"/> 
        <jrc 
    destdir="./compiled_jasper"
    tempdir="./compiled_jasper"
    keepjava="true"
    xmlvalidation="true">
            <src>
                <fileset dir="./report">
                    <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
                </fileset>
            </src>
            <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
        </jrc> 
    </target> 
</project>
```

The folder structure:

```
report
  report_with_scriplet.jrxml
compile_report.xml
```

After the running sript folder structure will be:

```
report
  report_with_scriplet.jrxml
compiled_jasper
  report_with_scriplet_1323195663885_780040.groovy
  report_with_scriplet.jasper
compile_report.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know where we specify the sciptlet class path when compiling the jrxml? I can't see it in the build.xml

Comment: A kind of..I though the scriptlet class path will be indicated there. Do have any idea how the link is made between the scriptlet class path and the jrxml when compiling?

Comment: I've got this: Unexpected element {}path {antlib: org.apache.tools.ant} path

Comment: @maya-bf Just add sample to answer